# AlloyUI modal reuse modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, yui, alloy-ui

I'm working on a AlloyUI modal window that is present in many pages of my application. The modal structure is actually the same, the only thing that changes is the bodyContent text for each page. I'm trying to reuse the AlloyUI modal script, only updating the bodyContent parameter rather than create 20 modal scripts for each page, but it's script nightmare for me as I have not found any code I can look at. I created a jsfiddle as an example and down below is the script I've been working. I'd appreciate your help.

http://jsfiddle.net/x9t3q0bs/

```
YUI().use('aui-modal', function(Y) {

  var helpModConfIdent              = Y.one('#showHelpPageConfirmIdentification'),
      helpModQuestions              = Y.one('#showHelpPageQuestions'),
      helpPageConfirmIdentRetCust   = Y.one('#showHelpPageConfirmIdentRetCust')


  var modal = new Y.Modal({
    bodyContent: "<p>Here will show help modal1.</p>",
    centered: true,
    destroyOnHide: false,
    headerContent: '<h3>Help info</h3>',
    modal: true,
    render: '#modal',
    visible: false,
    width: 800, 
    toolbars: {
    }
  });



modal.addToolbar([{
    label: 'Close',
    cssClass: 'btn-primary-content',
    on: {
      click: function() {
        modal.hide();
      }
    }
  }]);

  modal2 = new Y.Modal(
      {
      bodyContent: "<p>Here will show help modal2.</p>",
        centered: true,
        destroyOnHide: false,
        headerContent: '<h3>Help info</h3>',
        modal: true,
        render: '#modal',
        visible: false,
        width: 800, 
        toolbars: {
        }
      }
    );





      if (helpModConfIdent) {
        helpModConfIdent.on('click', function (e) {
          modal.show();
        });
      } else if (helpModQuestions) {
        helpModQuestions.on('click', function (e) {
          modal2.show();
        });
      }

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bodyContent` is one of the attributes that is available to be [set](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.Modal.html#method_set) if you have access to the modal instance. Otherwise, you can always manipulate the html within the template that has been rendered.

```js
YUI().use('aui-modal', function(Y) {
 
 var modal = new Y.Modal({
    bodyContent: "<p>Default implementation</p>",
    centered: false,
    destroyOnHide: false,
    headerContent: '<h3>Help info</h3>',
    modal: true,
    render: '#modal',
    visible: false,
    width: 250
  });
      
      Y.one('#modalInstance').on('click', function(){
             modal.set('bodyContent', "<p>Something loaded using the orginal modal instance</p>")
             modal.show()
           }) 
   
      Y.one('#nodeInstance').on('click', function (e) {    
           Y.one('#modal .modal-content .modal-body').setHTML('<p>Set using the node instance</p>')
           modal.show()
        })
 
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.0/aui/aui-min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.0/aui-css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>

 
<div id='modalInstance'>Modal Instance</div>
<br/>
<div id='nodeInstance'>Node Instance</div>

<div class="yui3-skin-sam">
  <div id="modal"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: By the way, maybe you could shed some light on another alloyUI/yui issue regarding the form validation. I posted another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953713/yui-input-group-validation

Comment: Can you please also tell how can we dynamically add or remove the buttons from the modal that is created. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I have visited your jsfiddle page and I found out the addtoolbar method. I think it will work. Although I could not run that jsfiddle page. Don't know how to run it.

Comment: @muasif80 The fiddle in the OP doesn't have all the necessary html to work. And yes `addToolbar` is one way to manipulate what control elements appear within the modal.  [Official Documentation Example](http://alloyui.com/examples/modal/real-world/)